# Re-Use Authorization to use with AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges in another program execution?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have a CLI-tool which creates an authorization and then uses it execute a command authorized. I need to call this CLI-tool a number of times in a row.

How do I re-use the authorization given when I called the tool for the first time?
This is my authorization-code:

```
AuthorizationRef authorizationRef;
status = AuthorizationCreate(NULL, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, &authorizationRef);
AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges(authorizationRef, "/bin/rm", kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, NULL  , NULL);
```

Comment: I assume you mean that you've tried just using `authorizationRef` multiple times and it didn't work? What error did you receive when you tried to reuse it?

Comment: No I mean that I'm calling the tool above, then calling it again. Therefore it asks again for username and password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `AuthorizationMakeExternalForm` to create a serializable version of your authorization token. You can store this for a limited time for use between your applications. Deserialize it with `AuthorizationCreateFromExternalForm`. See [Authorization Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/03authtasks/authtasks.html) for details. A key detail that is kind of buried is the constant `kAuthorizationExternalFormLength`. You'll need that to know how big an object you're serializing (it's 32 bytes, but use the constant).

This token is extremely sensitive, so you must be very careful with how you store it. It is generally better to create a separate privileged helper tool that your application can communicate with. See [EvenBetterAuthorizationSample](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/EvenBetterAuthorizationSample/Introduction/Intro.html) for sample code on how to do this in 10.8+ using XPC. (If you need pre-10.8, there used to be sample code called BetterAuthorizationSample that worked back to 10.6. Apple has taken it down, but you can find copies with google).

A privileged helper tool is more complicated to set up, but is much more secure. You use launchd to start it, then you pass it an authentication token (using `AuthorizationMakeExternalForm`). Launchd will automatically keep it running (and therefore authenticated) until it's been idle for a period of time. Then launchd will automatically kill it. This gets rid of all the security headaches of writing the auth token to a file.

Answer (score 2):

Note that AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges has been deprecated for quite some time now.

As @RobNapier suggests in his comprehensive answer, you should be creating a helper app that is registered with launchd, which will provide the required elevation for the helper.

The EvenBetterAuthorizationSample is what you should be aiming for, but it's quite involved if you're coming to it for the first time, especially as it uses XPC communication between the application and its helper.

[SMJobBless](https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/samplecode/SMJobBless/Introduction/Intro.html) is a simpler example that can help you get started and understand the concepts for creating a separate helper application.